# Render from part of data in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I have all_product_cellinfo.js, and i render it by {all_product_cellinfo}.Map
That is will render all data from array all_product_cellinfo

**How to render only product have id:1?**

(all_product_cellinfo.js)

```
let all_product_cellinfo = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name:"Iphone 15 Pro",
        Description: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.", 
        categories: "Iphone",
        color: 4,
        image: img_1,
        new_price: 100,
        old_price:50, 
        button_1: "Order",
        button_2: "View more",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name:"Iphone 15 Pro",
        Description: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.", 
        categories: "Iphone",
        color: 4,
        image: img_1,
        new_price: 100,
        old_price:50,
        button_1: "Order",
        button_2: "View more",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name:"Iphone 15 Pro",
        Description: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.", 
        categories: "Iphone",
        color: 4,
        image: img_1,
        new_price: 100,
        old_price:50, 
        button_1: "Order",
        button_2: "View more",
    },
]
```

(ItemsProductDisplay.jsx)

```
<div className='ItemsProduct'>
      <img src={props.image} alt="" />
      <div className="content-descript">
        <p className="title-card-product">{props.name} </p>
        <p className="sub-title-card-product">{props.Description}</p>
        <div className="button-product-card">
          <button className="Button-order">{props.button_1}</button>
          <Link to="/ProductOfCellinfo/{2}"><button className="Button-more">{props.button_2}</button></Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

(ProductDisplay.jsx)

```
const ProductDisplay = () => {
    return (
        <div className='Product-Display' >
            {all_product_cellinfo.map((items, i) => {
                return <ItemsProductDisplay key={i} {...items} />
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `<ItemsProductDisplay {...all_product_cellinfo[0]}>`? Or are you saying you don't know where it is in the array and want to find it?

Comment: Use `find()` or `filter()`.

Comment: i mean i want to find items with id:1 and render only id:1 in (ProductDisplay.jsx)

Comment: `yourList.filter((el) => el.id === 1).map(() => xxxx)` will work for you.